# JavaScript Library for mobile animations?

Tags: animation, mobile, css, javascript

I'm looking for a JavaScript Library similar to impress.js, with which I can create animations on text content, but which works also in iOS/Android.

[Hype](http://tumultco.com/hype/) by Tumult goes into the direction I'm looking for, but I'm not looking for an editor but for something I can build into my app.

I was focused on JS the whole time but can CSS3 do similar things on mobile, too?

Thanks for the answers!

Comment: _If you want something to be done well do it using jQuery_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few options I looked at before:

[jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/)

[Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch)

[jQTouch](http://www.jqtouch.com/)

Imo jQuery Mobile being the most reliable + the developing speed with it is fast + it is really simple to use and it is not beta anymore!

You could also go by using the canvas element -  [cakejs](http://code.google.com/p/cakejs/) and [raphaeljs](http://raphaeljs.com/) are an option to it.

CSS3 will give you some options - altough using webkit really expands your CSS3 options - but you loose on crossbrowser support.

Comment: jQuery Mobile and Raphael.js look very interesting, thanks!